# Run-Time Error 6069

Tags: vba, excel

Hello guys i have loop which opens for me Inline Shape (xlsx file attached in doc). It works fine but sometimes i get an error:

> ```
>   Run-time error 6069
> ```

It informs that i try to open excel application and probably it's not installed (WOW).  When i debug it highlights a lane

```
wddoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.Activate
```

I press "Run" and it works normally like there was no error.
But it's frustrating cause i need to interfere and user who will use this tool can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be some timeout issue. You may try to repeat operation for a while:

```
...
timeout = Now + #00:00:01# 'Try for 1 second max
On Error Resume Next
Do
    Err.Clear
    wddoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.Activate
    Doevents 'Sometimes you need to allow events to succeed in some methods
Loop While Err.Number=0 Or Now>timeout
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Coudn't make call..."
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End If
On Error GoTo 0 'or whatever error handler you were using
...
```